# /dev/disk/by-uuid/ not working on one machine

Tags: disk, uuid, iscsi

I have a iSCSI disk which I am mounting from several machines (exclusively, not concurrently).

On machine `A`, I start iscsi `service open-iscsi start` and the iscsi disk is discovered as `/dev/sdb1`. Also, the `UUID` gets added in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`

On machine `B` I start iscsi `service open-iscsi start` and the iscsi disk is also discovered as `/dev/sdb1`. However, no `UUID` is generated (but `UUID` for other disks works fine)

Why would UUID work on one machine, but not on another?

I am using Debian Wheezy

**UPDATE**: I have discovered, that when I run `partprobe` the UUID suddenly appears in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`. However, when I stop `iscsi` and start it again, the UUID is not there. Do I have to run `partprobe` every time?

**UPDATE2**: the iscsi disk is 4TB. My suspicion is that this is causing the problem (because it is larger than 2TB)

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the operating systems and versions of the machines involved.

Comment: I am using Debian Wheezy. I have updated my question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: So both machines are using the same version of debian?

Comment: the iSCSI initiator is running Debian, whereas the iSCSI image is hosted on a QNAP storage system

Answer (score 2):

When you discover your iscsi disk try running this command :

```
sudo /sbin/blkid
```

You should get all the UUIDs of your disks.

Output:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="ce55950a-2dfe-4dc4-84b9-079d4b36f3e3" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="jmEnPF-vjb6-PrHJ-BQ4s-0jpw-YjO5-47Q7be" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="Y82rfl-jW79-6MQn-3W5A-Kaw4-i1ma-i986HJ" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
...
```

What type of OS are you running ?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you're running the same `kpartx` versions on both hosts. There was a bug in the `kpartx.rules` file introduced in an update to wheezy. The latest version of kpartx fixed this regression.

It might be necessary to reboot (to reload the udev rules) after upgrading kpartx.

Answer (score -1):

Is `udev` working properly on your server?

`udev` is the device mapper in charge of the creation of those symlinks, so it can be that it is not working, or that it is not configured properly.

Is it running? (i.e. `/etc/init.d/udev status`)

It may be that it is not configured properly, so check if your rules are OK:

```
$ grep "disk/by-uuid" /lib/udev/rules.d/*
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules:ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem|other|crypto", ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-uuid/$env{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}"
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:  SYMLINK+="disk/by-uuid/$env{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}"
(...)
```

Note that the actual rules might be different.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: I know, but since I cannot comment I had to put it like an answer (indeed, it may be the actual answer).

Comment: If this is "an actual answer" then you should explain how to establish whether `udev` is running, what it is and how to enable if it isn't.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I reviewed ["Is udev running in your server?"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/118428/1) (IIRC in the LQ queue). That answer is inappropriate as an answer, it should have been a comment, and I flagged it so, do **you** disagree with that? Alvaro had enough rep for commenting. The answer was later expanded, my flag (which automatically inserts the text, I now removed) was declined, but the system never gives a reviewer a message to re-review an answer, nor does it retract the text it inserts. Had Alvaro used `@anthon` I would have know about the change and his comment

Comment: @Alvaro - You have 200 rep, how are you not able to comment?

Comment: @CharlesStewart - if you have leads or partial ideas then those are comments, this isn't up for discussion, that's just how it is. If you're unfamiliar with this then please read the help on how to answer questions.

Comment: @Anthon - yes I fixed it.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I am not sure what you disagree with as that link supports my action. The first point at "When should I use this flag" is **Use this flag when an answer is being used to  Ask a question**. The whole answer was the sentence "Is udev running in your server?" and ends with a question mark. And you don't think it is a question, but a partial answer because of what?

Comment: @CharlesStewart Which FAQ text are referring to?

Comment: @CharlesStewart According to your standards no question or communication (both reasons for flagging according to Robert Harvey) can be flagged, as they always can rephrased. I might just not be smart enough to see that they could but turned into that. And if you were right I should have a lot more flags rejected than I have.

Comment: @Anthon - I do not think anything I have said would be controversial on the other Stackexchange sites I am familiar with.  I am really astonished at this dialogue - as I suppose you are.  Perhaps a meta qn is in order, either here or on meta.SO.

Comment: @CharlesStewart First of all slm flagged this as well. and I don't understand why you only address me on this issue and not him as well Second: I have somewhat less helpful flags on [so] (almost 300) than on [unix.se] but the same behaviour in flagging and comparable number of rejects (some bloopers, some edited before being moved to comment/deleted, just as this one). I am sure that if Alvaro had waited even longer than the half-hour between posting his question and expanding upon it it would have been turned into a comment by the mods/10K+ers here, or deleted.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I also flagged this as not an answer, it would be considered as such in all of the 5 SE sites where I have enough rep to have an opinion. Comments are for asking for clarifications, answers are for posting solutions.

Comment: Just for the record, I did not vote on this answer

Comment: @CharlesStewart - This conversation is fruitless here, this A is not an A, it's a comment. Let's move this to a meta question either here or on meta.SO to get an actual decision. Sitting here and badgering Anthon and others who are highly viewed within this site's community is doing nothing constructive. Anthon has performed a lot of the reviews on this site as well as other SE sites and hasn't gotten any indications from those site's mods that he's doing it wrong!

Comment: The DV is from me. This is a comment! Expand it to an A and I'll gladly revert it as always!

Comment: @Anthon: I didn't use the '@' to signal slm because the Stack Exchange software has a limit whereby it only notifies one person.  I'm prepared to accept that my interpretation is wrong, but my interpretation is the one that is followed on the Tex-SX site.  I'll raise this question on meta in due course.

Comment: @slm: Anthon is clearly conscientious and an asset to the site; this is only an argument about interpretation of rule. I agree that this discussion should take place on Meta.

Comment: @CharlesStewart - OK, since you had the original feedback can you please take the lead on asking this Q? Please post a link to it in the U&L chatroom, we've diagressed this comment thread enough 8-)

Comment: In my opinion this is clearly an answer, and people got rather hung up on a question mark. If he'd said "Make sure that udev is working properly, it handles that folder", everything would've been fine, but he said "Is udev working properly?" instead.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I would not have flagged this answer in its current form. Can you please comment on the initial version of this answer, being appropriately flagged? That [version of this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/118428/1) is what caused me to flag; the system to insert the "not an answer" comment; and got this whole exchange (and its [meta counterpart](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/2800/33055)) rolling.

Comment: @Anthon: when I posted my original answer I did not have reputation at all (therefore I couldn't post a comment), I obtained it afterwards.

Comment: @slm: see my comment above: I did not have enough reputation when the question was posted.

Comment: @Alvaro I realised that you did not have enough rep to comment while trying to track down what happened. IMHO you should not have posted the initial version of you answer, but you could have started with "I think this has to do with udev not running, you can check that with .. and if it is not ....). Not having enough rep is not an excuse to misuse answers possibilities to leave questions or communicate with the OP. Sorry your elaborated answer got picked upon so much after Charles' comments on us flagging your first version.

Comment: @Anthon - Thanks for clarifying. That makes sense now, as to why you posted this. I'l leave it with what Anthon said above, the original A wasn't appropriate, recasting it as Anthon suggested would've been a better approach.

Comment: As @Anthon posted, I moved the discussion to http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/a-disagreement-about-the-rules-on-non-answer-answers and I am now deleting my comments that are echoed there.  This incident is an example of a race condition in open Q&A-site moderation, I suppose.